# Landing page on root document: what about Google?

Tags: google, google-ranking, landing-page

We're about to launch a new site where one idea is to place a landing page with only static content and a signup-button on the root page (e.g. https://www.domain.tld/) and *all* other content not linked at all unless a user is registered and logged in. That other existing content would be properly listed within some sitemaps and ready for indexing.

I tried to find out what Google thinks about such a setup but had no success (yet). E.g. does it affect ranking and/or indexability as such of our new domain/root page?

Edit: All other content is *not* behind a login and accessible via a direct page request.

Comment: If Google can't access the content because it is behind a login then you cannot expect it to be indexed.whether you put it in a sitemap or not. That one page will be crawled and indexed but the rest will be ignored.

Comment: I need to clarify: the rest of the content is not behind a login, it will be accessible, but not linked from the web root.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds bad UX, build a site that is easy to use and has rich content.

For example, consider a one-page site and have relevant links to your services contact info about sections all on one page.

Comment: No we can't consider a one-page site- we already have many many pages but we want to increase (free) signups. This is about what Google thinks regarding a front-page landing-page without any links to go further except to signup / login.

Comment: Take a look at popular subscription sites like Netflix they have a one-page site that offers rich content and if they want to see more they will need to sign up.

Comment: Netflix has virtually no other content on their public site - we are a content distribution platform with with lot's of rich content accessible and which need to be indexed - all while we aim to increase signup conversion rates.

That's a totally different setup than the one of Netflix.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but what I meant is that Netflix has a great example of a landing page providing the user rich content about what Netflix is all about.